# Programmer for IC 24AA64I/SN other than MPLAB?

Tags: mplab

Is there any suitable software and programmer device that suitable for IC 24AA64I/SN other than MPLAB?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try the ProMax4G

http://cupio.co.uk/pormax-4g/

Another list ist here: [MC programmer](https://www.microchipdirect.com/product/programmers)